# Automatically use bold font with web font faces?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have a web font family with different weights, such as

```
@font-face { font-family: 'merriweatherregular'; etc. }
@font-face { font-family: 'merriweatherbold'; etc.}
```

My site uses multiple fonts, and I am using this font on items such as `p` tags, as in

```
p { font-family: merriweatherregular, georgia, serif; }
```

There's some legacy text though that maybe wrapped in `span`, `div` or nothing at all.

There's text that's wrapped in `b`,`strong`,`em`, or `i` or a combination. When I style text as above `p` tag example, the bolded words therein are not in bold.  Obviously, for the `p` tags I can use `p b { font-family: merriweatherbold;}` but not all the other random instances.  And I can't apply the font-family to all `b, strong` since there are instance of that in another font altogether.

I found [this tip](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/) but it's from 2010 and refers to a Safari bug, not sure if it's still valid.

What's the proper way to set this up so all the tags like  `b`,`strong`,`em`, or `i` work as expected?

**UPDATE**
The tip [linked to above](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/) and originally [found here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045859/how-to-use-font-weight-with-font-face-fonts) seems to work still. Anyone know if there are **any** downsides?

**UPDATE 2**
There is an issue.  IE8 doesn't work properly.  It just showed all my text in the italic variant.  It seems to want separate names.  Thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use font-weight with font-face fonts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045859/how-to-use-font-weight-with-font-face-fonts)

Comment: Yes, I linked to that post in my question.

Comment: If you have issues with answers to old questions, you should focus on getting them improved, *not* spawn new copies of the question.