# Custom font is not showing on Electron + Vue App

Tags: vue.js, build, fonts, electron, electron-builder

I am developing an app using [Vue + Electron](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) and im facing an issue using custom fonts. When running the app in web mode, the icons used with the custom font show ok. But when i build the app using electron-builder, the icons/custom font are not loaded.

I import the custom font in the index.html head tag and the custom fonts are located in src/renderer/assets/fonts folder.

Any help
Thanks

Comment: You will need to make sure your fonts are compiled into electron. This is would be done by webpack when you import the fonts into your source. eg. into your javascript or css. Not in your index.html

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-fonts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make sure that the font is included in electron, try something like this:

In your renderer main.js

`import './scss/app.scss'`

In your './scss/app.scss'

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Your Custom Font';
    src: url('../assets/fonts/Your Custom Font.ttf');
}
```

This should make sure that your font is included with electron by webpack.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-fonts

Comment: To load multiple versions of the same font-family, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28339483/2065702).