# Custom font in Electron + React application not working after running the Windows installer

Tags: reactjs, electron, font-face, electron-builder

I'm building an Electron app that needs to run on Windows. The stack exists of React + Typescript, SCSS + TailwindCSS. The style is compiled with postcss. The Electron app is built with `electron-builder`.

After compiling the style, creating new Electron installer for Windows and running this installer the included font's don't seem to work.

When checking the `build` folder that functions as the output folder for `electron-builder`, all font files are present in the `static/media` folder. If I check the link to the font files when the Electron app is running, the link in the CSS also links to the generated `static` folder where the files are.

**Files & code**

- The font files are located in: `src/assets/font/`;
- For each weight I use (only 2) there are: `.ttf`, `.woff`, `woff2`, `.svg` and `.eot` available;
- The font is loaded through SASS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url('../font/Montserrat-Medium.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../font/Montserrat-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../font/Montserrat-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/Montserrat-Medium.svg') format('svg'),
         url('../font/Montserrat-Medium.eot') format('eot');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url('../font/Montserrat-Bold.ttf') format('truetype')
         url('../font/Montserrat-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../font/Montserrat-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/Montserrat-Bold.svg') format('svg'),
         url('../font/Montserrat-Bold.eot') format('eot');
}
```

- Then it is loaded in TailwindCSS as basic font, configured in the **tailwindconfig**:

```
theme: {
    fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Montserrat', 'sans-serif'],
        body: ['Montserrat'],
        bold: ['Montserrat']
    },
... rest of config file
```

**Facts**

- The font works if it is installed locally on Windows.
- When it's not found, the app doesn't fallback to a `sans-serif` font.
- The font files and link to the font files is correct when checking the CSS in the running application (Chromium element inspector).
- All other styles work correctly, only the font isn't working. So it looks like the CSS is compiled and loaded properly.

**Checked resource**

- [Custom font is not showing on Electron + Vue App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60479802/custom-font-is-not-showing-on-electron-vue-app) (yes it's Vue, but the answer still is: use `@font-face`).
- https://www.reddit.com/r/electronjs/comments/bhaiva/how_to_load_custom_fonts_in_electron_app/
- https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-use-specific-font-in-electron-app/32215
- https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack/issues/163
- https://dev.to/theola/electron-app-with-webpack-bootstrap-fontawesome-and-jquery-a-complete-guide-54k2

**Questions**

1. When running the `installer.exe` that is created with `electron-builder`, do you need to include an assets folder and/or other files in the installation folder (e.g.: `builder-effective-config.yaml`)?
2. Are there other ways to include a local font? I don't want to use a CDN or other online source.

All resources I currently found say it should work when using `@font-face`.

**Note**: if you require more information, please let me know and I'll provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a little more testing/checking the issue was the React build. It loaded an older configuration, that was breaking the font load.

Thanks all who read it!