# Self-hosted fonts doesnt works on Next.js

Tags: css, fonts, next.js, font-face, woff2

**What I want and what I wonder**

I would like to use self-hosted font within a Next.js application

**What i already tried**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuIwB.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6ekH.png

**The result**

In both cases CSS only recognizes the last font

**Important**

My Bold, Medium, Italic and regular fonts are separeted file, they are all in woff2 format.
I already tried to use diferente @font-face for each file (bold,regular and medium) and name each one, it works, but i think could be a more eficient way

Comment: type Mitropolis without the single quotation marks

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279989/multiple-font-weights-one-font-face-query

Comment: Please make sure to post code as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @juliomalves Thank you for the advice I'll make sure that next time I do better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add one `@font-face` per style (including weights and italic versions).
**The `font-family` name should stay the same!**
Otherwise styles won't get mapped correctly to the specific font files.

Currently you're just overriding your first `url` – "Metropolis-Medium.woff2" won't be loaded at all since it's replaced by "Metropolis-Bold.woff2".

Multiple URLs can be used for fallback formats (e.g woff2, woff2, ttf etc.)

Without any `font-weight` values the browser will map the family-name "Metropolis" to "Metropolis-Bold.woff2" file and regular font-weight (or 400).

For better compatibility, you should use more verbose rules like so:
(Albeit some browsers might be more forgiving)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Metropolis;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../../../public/fonts/metropolis/Metropolis-Regular.woff2")
      format("woff2"),
    url("../../../public/fonts/metropolis/Metropolis-Regular.woff")
      format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Metropolis;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url("../../../public/fonts/metropolis/Metropolis-Italic.woff2")
      format("woff2"),
    url("../../../public/fonts/metropolis/Metropolis-Italic.woff")
      format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Metropolis;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../../../public/fonts/metropolis/Metropolis-Medium.woff2")
      format("woff2"),
    url("../../../public/fonts/metropolis/Metropolis-Medium.woff")
      format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Metropolis;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../../../public/fonts/metropolis/Metropolis-Bold.woff2")
      format("woff2"),
    url("../../../public/fonts/metropolis/Metropolis-Bold.woff") format("woff");
}

body {
  font-family: Metropols, sans-serif;
}

.medium {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```