# Some Google font doesn't have Semibold font type

Tags: flutter, fonts, google-fonts

I am using google font for my app development.

I want to use semibold font, but google font doesn't have semibold font. is there a workaround to use semibold font.

for example

OpenSans (semibold) font - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans

Roboto (Doesn't have semibold font) - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that Roboto currently doesn't provide a dedicated semibold/600 font-weight.

But these intermediate weights are not standardized – so it's more important to choose a font-family providing the desired **visual font-weight**.

[image: Open Sans semibold 600]
[image: Roboto medium 500]
[image: Montserrat semibold 600]

Example: Open sans, Roboto, Montserrat

As you can see, the numerical font-weights don't necessarily result in comparable visual levels of "boldness".

#### Roboto variable font?

Actually there is already an available Roboto variable font: [Roboto Flex](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Flex?query=roboto&vfonly=true)
Unfortunately, there is currently no way to download more fine grained intermediate styles as static font files (like e.g. Open Sans).

But it is quite likely, that google fonts will also provide/update the currently available Roboto font-family in the near future.

But it's also important to understand that these updates will only happen, if the actual font designers can afford to update freely available fonts (So "google fonts" are not created by google itself).

In other words – there's no way to "automagically" generate proper variable fonts. Even though the main concept of interpolation has been used for decades in font design (E.g. Variable Font's predecessor was  Adobe's Multiple Master concept – not the same but quite similar).

So, it's still tricky, but more and more fonts will eventually support even more style variations.

Answer (score 0):

try this 'FontWeight.w600'

```
Text(
  'This is Google Fonts',
  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
   textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,),
  ),
),
```

Comment: how to use it? where to add this code?