# font-face to import special font into website but it did not work well in safari

Tags: css, fonts, safari

I am using @font-face to import Hack font ttf file into my website like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Hack;
    src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hack-font/3.3.0/web/hack.min.css");
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    // src: url("\font\Hack-Bold.ttf");
    // src: url("\font\Hack-Regular.ttf");
    // src: url("\font\Hack-BoldItalic.ttf");
}
```

it renders well in chrome and desktop but it did not rendered in safari. wandering to know how to fix it.Thx!

I try to delete the cache in the safari but it did not work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@font-face` rule is wrong.
Probably you see the font applied on desktop because you've also installed it locally.

Since your font is hosted on a cdn you need to load the font via `link` element or `@import` like so:

`link` in your HTML `<head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hack-font/3.3.0/web/hack.min.css">
```

`@import` in your main css file

```
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hack-font/3.3.0/web/hack.min.css");
```

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hack-font/3.3.0/web/hack.min.css");


body{
    font-family: Hack;
}
```

```html
<p>Should be hack font-family</p>
```

##### Further reading:

[mdn docs: How to use "@font-face"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)
[SO question: Multiple font-weights, one @font-face query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279989/multiple-font-weights-one-font-face-query)

Comment: Thx I already import this font by using css file via