# How to name multiple variations of the font when there are 40+ within one font family

Tags: css, fonts

I came to the problem with naming font flavors within one font-family. The project I'm implementing is using 10 of them.

The font in question is Sequel Sans and it has 48 flavors. One can download it from [here](https://www.dfonts.org/fonts/sequel-sans-font/) if interested.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28339483/2570350) post, but my issue goes beyond that. I did first one like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Sequel Sans';
  src: url('Sequel Sans Book Disp.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

but not really sure about naming the other 9 (not to mention more, but 10 is what I'm working with now). Any resource I could read that goes about this problem? Especially that font weights for each are not provided (would they be I would just go after that and call it a day).

Comment: You should only load the font weights and variations you really need, I doubt you'll need 48 of them. Just duplicate your font-face block, change the filename and set a different font-weight property to distinguish them (doesn't really matter if the file names include those, you can set this up as you like, a bold font can be font-weight:100 in your css)

Comment: @rx2347 but they don't have specified weights and that's also the issue, not sure how to name when they are not even specified in that matter really

Comment: also it's not like I need 10 fonts, but designer somehow came to think that

Comment: Well, you know how loading and naming works, the rest is really up to you.

Comment: yeah, I just thought maybe there is some semi-standard for that or convention at least. Thanks