# Layout shift with variable font only

Tags: css, fonts, variable-fonts

I'm using wordpress with a theme framework where you can customize most of the stuff with clicks. It's not the ideal situation, but I saw 99 performance points in Google pagespeed for a fairly complex layout and I tried to put up with it. Besides Google fonts I can use my own hosted ones. I add a new font, select a weight and attach an uploaded file with that font weight. And repeat the process under that font for as many weights I need. And whatever I use it is called in the header with *@font-face*

If I want to use a variable font the only option I have now is to select every font weight I need and attach to it the same variable font file.

When I have, let's say 5 *@font-face* declarations with 5 static font files I get no text flash( FOUT). When I have 5 *@font-face* declarations with the same variable font on each - due to my theme limitation - the text flash until my font loads it's quite noticeable.

If someone could give me a little help at least to understand. This is an variable fonts known problem? Or it is due my theme limitation and one *@font-face* declaration with `"weight: 300-700"` would solve the problem? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is this just because the variable font is one, larger request that tqakes longer than 5 smaller, same-time requests? Maybe try to throttle your network speed (Devtools > Network > Throttle) and see if the problem gets even more noticeable. Sadly enough, it won't be possible to _speed that up_, so your best bet is to wait for it to load or something and then show the page.

Comment: I understand your explanation. Though that font problem get's me puzzled. If I have 5 different font weights, as how my theme works now, at 40kb each I get no FOUT. If I have 5 @font-face declarations with the same variable version, at 60kb, wich teoretically should be loaded only once by the browser, I get FOUT.

Comment: You don't need 5 @font-face rules. Quite likely, there are errors in your css. you don't separate weights with a hyphen but with an empty space `weight: 300 700`. See also [Multiple font-weights, one @font-face query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279989/multiple-font-weights-one-font-face-query/74618718#74618718)