# How to declare CSS font-face with font-weight and font-style properly?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to use the **`@font-face`** CSS property to define my ttf fonts locally as follows:

<kbd>**open-sans.css**</kbd>

```
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        src: url('OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
      }
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        src: url('OpenSans-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: normal;
      }
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        src: url('OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
      }
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        src: url('OpenSans-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-style: normal;
      }
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        src: url('OpenSans-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: italic;
      }
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        src: url('OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: bolder;
        font-style: normal;
      }
```

But, unfortunately, it's not working, and the browser (**Iceweasel 38.6.1**) always show me the last one (extra bold one). I followed also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21614532/1977778), which seems to be the best one until now.

What's I'm doing wrong?

P.S.

I need to use the *Open Sans* font-face locally, without any internet connection, so **Google Fonts API does not feet in my scenario**.

**EDIT**

1. `ttf` files are in the same directory of the CSS;
2. <kbd>open-sans.css</kbd> is imported as the first CSS file;
3. font properties for text in the page is:

   ```
   font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   ```

But it always loads the last one declared on the CSS.

Comment: have you downloaded and saved the font in your folder?

Comment: Yes. The fonts are all in place. I added further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a number of reasons why it doesn't work:

1. Your paths to the font files are not correct (make sure the `.css` file is in the same folder with the `.ttf` files. If they're not, make sure the paths in your CSS point to the correct location.
2. Your browser might not be able to render `.ttf` files. Please check and, if necessary, provide additional file formats (`.eot`,`.woff`, `.svg`) for cross-browser compatibility. You might want to use a web-font generator for this. My personal favorite is [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), but I don't recommend or endorse it. I just use it. :)
3. Perhaps you're not referencing the `@font-face` correctly in your CSS? Correct form is:

```css
your-element.your-class {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal|bold|{exact-weight};
  font-style: normal|italic;
}
```

Also, please note that the `@font-face` must be declared ***before*** you use it. CSS reads once, only goes forward and must be able to interpret the code when it reads it.

Note: `bolder` and `lighter` are not valid CSS values for `font-weight` property inside `@font-face` descriptor (as very well pointed out by [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock), in the comments). It is recommended to use exact font weights (100 - 900) to make sure your font is rendered the same cross-browser. (i.e.: replace `font-weight: bolder;` with `font-weight: 900;` and `font-weight: lighter;` with `font-weight: 200;`). (Or use your preferred values, of course).

Comment: bolder and lighter are not valid values for the `font-weight` font-face descriptor (which is what the question is talking about), but they are valid values for the `font-weight` property (which you are referring to in your answer). The key is differentiating between the two.

Comment: I've found the cause of the problem. As you point out, `bolder` and `lighter` are not valid values for `font-weight`, although [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp) these values are reported as acceptable. Thank you.