# how to add fonts to webpage when it's several weighted fonts are in same name?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm designing a wesite and came up with some problems on this. The font i'm using is **Raleway** and there are variations of the font like **Raleway, Raleway Thin** etc.
[The design i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1zn2.png)

in this design above one (Come Find Me ) is in Raleway and below one (Swatry's like a Melody) is in Raleway Thin. therefore i came up with below css.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v11/yQiAaD56cjx1AooMTSghGfY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v11/0dTEPzkLWceF7z0koJaX1A.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'RalewayLight';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    src: local('Raleway Thin'), local('Raleway-Thin'),local('RalewayLight'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v11/rr0ijB5_2nAJsAoZ6vECXRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'RalewayLight';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    src: local('Raleway Thin'),local('RalewayLight'), local('Raleway-Thin'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v11/RJMlAoFXXQEzZoMSUteGWFtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

in css, classes are like this.

```
.topPageTitle{
    font-family: "Raleway","sans-serif";
    color: #159c96;
    font-size: 5vw;
}
.topPageSubtitle{
    font-family: "RalewayLight","sans-serif";
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2.5vw;

}
```

And Html is this.

```
<span class="topPageTitle">Come Find Me </span>
<span class="topPageSubtitle">Swatry's like a Melody</span>
```

this works fine for me, on **windows** and **fedora**. but in **mac**, this **doesn't** work properly and for the below text it's rendering Arial font.
what is the solution for this? is there any other proper way to **use both Raleway and Raleway Thin in one webpage?**

Comment: You can use google fonts directly by using '@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,400,500,700');' and use the font weight or font font size alone on specific CSS selectors independently.

Comment: tried that. doesn't work because that weight cannot be set by font-weight. there are separate fonts for each weight.

Comment: I hope this can help on font face with font weight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045859/how-to-use-font-weight-with-font-face-fonts