# How do you include custom fonts in Semantic UI (instead of Google Fonts)

Tags: semantic-ui

In `/src/site/globals/site.variables`, I can see how you can define google fonts, which get imported from when you compile. What I am interested in is defining my own custom fonts where I will supply my own font files.

I can’t find docs on how to do it. While I know how to do it in CSS, I am wondering if it is already built-in in this framework but I have simply missed it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a built-in way to do it. Here's how I did it.

I used the standard `@font-face` css rule. I then placed it in the `site.overrides` file. I am using a less variable (`@font-path`) to simplify my file paths.

```
@font-path: '../../fonts';
@font-face {
    font-family: 'my-font';
    src: url('@{font-path}/my-font.woff') format('woff'),
      url('@{proxima-prefix}my-font.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You'll have to make sure that the font files are served up appropriately by your server.

The above can be turned into a less mixin based on your usage as well.

A good resource on `@font-face` and formats: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

A great answer on how to use different font weights/styles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10046346/7681976

Comment: Thank you — I will try that!